# Cannot run a query using OpenAdmintool on my Informix DB, ERROR -272

Tags: informix

The connection to my db is working (i can browse through records) 
But when i want to execute a query using openadmin tool's SQL editor on my db , i get the following error:

Error: -272
[Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][Informix]No SELECT permission for syssqltrace. (SQLPrepare[-272] at ext\pdo_informix\informix_driver.c:131)

Query:
SELECT MAX(sql_id) AS sql_id FROM sysmaster:syssqltrace WHERE sql_sid = 265 AND sql_id < ( SELECT MAX(sql_id) FROM sysmaster:syssqltrace WHERE sql_sid = 265 )

Comment: I highly suggest people ot install RazorSQL!

Answer (score 0):

I installed RazorzSQL, which is perfect for browsing and executing sql statements

Comment: I don't think this will make any difference, as the errormessage is user specific: his user doesn't has select permissions on the table he wants to query.  The tool you use for executing the query doesn't solve this problem!